# Pagination - Discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to make a command that will display some information and then, when i react to an emote, its supposed to display another set of information.

I tried to use parts of [this](https://gist.github.com/noaione/58cdd25a1cc19388021deb0a77582c97), specifically the parts in line 335 to 393
to get it to work. However, it just does nothing. Not even an error message.

This is the code I use right now.

```py
            def check_react(reaction, user):
            if reaction.message.id != msg.id:
                return False
            if user != ctx.message.author:
                return False
            return True
        res, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check_react, timeout=None,)
        if user != ctx.message.author:
            print('if user != ctx.message.author:')
        elif '⬅️' in str(res.emoji):
            page -=1
            print(page)
            embed = discord.Embed(title='generic title', description='generic description', color=0x52fffc)
            await msg.edit(embed=embed)
        elif '➡️' in str(res.emoji):
            page +=1
            print(page)
            embed = discord.Embed(title='generic title 2', description='generic description 2', color=0x52fffc)
            await msg.edit(embed=embed)
```

It seems to stop at

> await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', ..)

why is that? and how can i make the code work? Thats in a cog btw. I'll happily provide more code if needed.

Comment: "It seems to stop at: await bot.wait_for('reaction_add)'". The function waits for an reaction_add. Or in other words it stops at that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot about this, and i figured it out eventually. Here's how i did it:

At first i put all the content of the pages in a list. Each entry is a page.

Then i define a function that will act as a check. This one will restrict the reaction listener to the actual embed that was sent and prevents anyone from reaction other than the command invoker. Sorry for any Formatting Errors.

```
def check(reaction, user):
   return reaction.message.id == msg.id and user == ctx.author #msg.id is the id of the embed sent by the bot.

page = 0

while True: #can be changed to a variable to let it work a certain amount of times.
   try:
       reaction, _ = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout= 20.0, check=check)
       if reaction.emoji == 'emote of choice here' and page > 0:
           page -= 1
           embed = discord.Embed(title='Title Here', description=pages[page]
           await msg.edit(embed=embed)
       if reaction.emoji == 'emote of choice here' and page < len(pages) -1:
           page += 1
           embed = discord.Embed(title='Title Here', description= pages[page]
           await msg.edit(embed=embed)
   except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      #do stuff here, could be pass or a message saying the timeout has been reached or something similar.
```

Comment: for some reason, the bot is stopping at the while loop and not continuing the command

Answer (score 5):

**Better and easier way is to use [DiscordUtils](https://pypi.org/projects/DiscordUtils/)**

Here is an example:

```
@commands.command()
async def paginate(self, ctx):
    embed1 = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color).add_field(name="Example", value="Page 1")
    embed2 = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color).add_field(name="Example", value="Page 2")
    embed3 = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color).add_field(name="Example", value="Page 3")
    paginator = DiscordUtils.Pagination.CustomEmbedPaginator(ctx, remove_reactions=True)
    paginator.add_reaction('⏮️', "first")
    paginator.add_reaction('⏪', "back")
    paginator.add_reaction('', "lock")
    paginator.add_reaction('⏩', "next")
    paginator.add_reaction('⏭️', "last")
    embeds = [embed1, embed2, embed3]
    await paginator.run(embeds)
```