# How to check a reaction of a message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Im trying to do some command with my bot like reaction roles and help command

Its something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
  em = discord.Embed(title="HELP",#etc
  #here is all about my help command
  my_msg = await ctx.send(embed=em)
  my_msg.add_reaction("#arrow-emoji)
  my_msg.add_reaction(#more arrow emoji
#...
  if #ctx.author react it:
    my_msg.edit(#page n)
```

So how can I do this?

Comment: Is this helping you? [Pagination - Discord.py rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877666/pagination-discord-py-rewrite)

Comment: @Dominik so the discord utils thingy should import it?

Comment: `import DiscordUtils as DiscordUtils` is the import

Comment: What's the purpose of that alias? Just `import DiscordUtils`

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Discord Pretty Help](https://pypi.org/project/discord-pretty-help/), its made for the purpose you want here!