# Reactions in discord.py

Tags: discord.py, command, bots

I'm very sorry to ask, but i got into a problem. I'm currently working on my discord.py bot, but now I got into the problem, that is like following:

I saw one of my friend's help command, that used reactions to move around in the help menu. Now i need sort of a command like that. It aren't for a help command, it's for another command, but that isn't what i'm talking about.

Now i need help on how to create these "reaction managers" if I can call them that...
Hope there is one out there who can help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pagination - Discord.py rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877666/pagination-discord-py-rewrite)

Comment: yes exactly like that

Comment: but it does not answer it as i had hoped

Comment: Well i found the answers i was looking for. Not by checking out your link, but searching it up on google

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit your message when someone adds reaction.
Here is my code that sends embed with all server emojis and their ids:

```
async def emid(ctx):
"""returns list of server emojis and their id"""
global coun
a = []
b = []
c = []
for emoji in ctx.guild.emojis:
    x = bot.get_emoji(emoji.id)
    a.append('\\' + str(x))
    a.append(str(x))
if len(a) > 21:
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        b.append(a[i])
        if i % 21 == 0 and i != 0:
            counter += 1
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title='Here is the list of server emojis:',
                description='\n'.join(b),
                colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(r.randint(100, 255), r.randint(100, 255), r.randint(100, 255))
            )
            b = []
            c.append(embed)
    message = await ctx.send(embed=c[0])
    message_id = message.id
    emoji = '⏩'
    emoji1 = '⏪'
    coun = 0
    await message.add_reaction(emoji1)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)

    @bot.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        global coun
        if payload.message_id == message_id and payload.emoji.name == '⏩':
            coun += 1
        elif payload.message_id == message_id and payload.emoji.name == '⏪':
            coun -= 1
        try:
            await message.edit(embed=c[coun])
        except:
            pass
else:
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Here is the list of server emojis:',
        description='\n'.join(a),
        colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(r.randint(100, 255), r.randint(100, 255), r.randint(100, 255))
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And btw there is a [library](https://pypi.org/project/discord-pretty-help/) to create help commands with reactions :)